# Reusing Testcontainers OracleContainer

Tags: spring, junit, testcontainers, testcontainers-junit5

It is possible to have the *testcontainers.reuse.enable* config on project *testcontainers.properties* instead of having on my user root folder?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible as it's a per-environment and not per-project configuration.

Follow the discussion in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/3780) for more information.

> `checks.disable` and `testcontainers.reuse.enable` are two exceptions to the rule of "any var can be configured with the classpath file", as they are considered advanced optimization techniques (and reuse mode even being a preview feature, not a stable solution). When it comes to advanced stuff, some level of research is expected.

Comment: I think it should work from an environment property -- https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/6cde564776d9af26e4b69f80e1344f1ea7d0f678/core/src/test/java/org/testcontainers/utility/TestcontainersConfigurationTest.java#L195

but it's still an environment setting and doesn't affect only the project. Use it wisely, especially in CI environments.